# trouble understanding an awk scrpt

Tags: bash, shell, awk, gawk

I'm having having issues understanding this gawk command. In summary it parses two log (local access) Tomcat log files for certain criteria.

Here is the function:

```
gawk 'function getip(rec) {n=split(rec,a,"\"");
        split(a[n-1],ip,",");return ip[1]}
    $10 ~ /302/ && $6 ~ /POST/ && $7 ~ /^\/sso\/lfe\/ui\/login/
    {lfe_user_ip=getip($0);
        user_path[lfe_user_ip]=user_path[lfe_user_ip]"_login-302"}
    /\/sso\/pfe\/rs\/profile\/customer/ && $6 ~ /PUT/
    {pfe_user_ip=getip($0);
        if (user_path[pfe_user_ip] ~ /_login-302/) {
            if ($10 ~ /200/) successful_redirect_conversion+=1;
            else failed_redirect_conversion+=1;} }
    END {print successful_redirect_conversion, failed_redirect_conversion}' \
        localhost_kff_access_log.2017-10-09.txt \
  /ses/var/late/dev001/tomcat/kfc/s002/logs/localhost_kfc_access_log.2017-10-09.txt
```

What I don't understand is the `split` method and also the escaping of the path as such:

```
$7 ~ /^\/sso\/lfe\/ui\/login/
```

Comment: It is escaping `/` because `/` is used as regex delimiter.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply!! any idea how the user_path variable works. didn't know you can do that

Comment: for split, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-split_0028_0029-function.... to avoid escaping `/`, you can use `$7 ~ "^/sso/lfe/ui/login"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `split` divides the input on literal double quotes and puts the results in `a`:

```
n=split(rec,a,"\"");
```

The value of `n` indicates how many fields we ended up with.  The next `split` takes the second to last of these fields and splits that on commas:

```
split(a[n-1],ip,",");
```

Finally, the function returns the first of these values:

```
return ip[1]
```

Without access to your input logs it's hard to say *exactly* what this accomplishes, but typically, something like

```
various values "some of them in quotes"  and "11.22.33.44,55.66.77.88,some more"
```

will take the last double-quoted field (the `n-1` is because `split` returns an empty field from after the last `"`) and further remove anything after the first comma, yielding the final result `11.22.33.44`.

Regarding the backslash, you have to escape any literal backslash in Awk regexes because the backslash itself is a regex delimiter.

```
$7 ~ /foo/bar/
```

is a syntax error because the slash looks like the regex ends after `foo` and the `bar/` is outside.  Putting in a backslash like `/foo\/bar/` allows the Awk parser to properly see that the internal slash is part of the regex, not its terminating delimiter.